# Update table row value to a random row value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have 2 MySQL tables.

**One table has a column that lists all the states**

```
colStates | column2 | column 3
------------------------------
AK        | stuff   | stuff
AL        | stuff   | stuff
AR        | stuff   | stuff
etc..     | etc..   | etc..
```

The second table has a column(randomStates) with all NULL values that need to be populated with a randomly selected state abbreviation.

Something like...

```
UPDATE mytable SET `randomStates`= randomly selected state value WHERE randomStates IS NULL
```

Can someone help me with this statement. I have looked around at other posts, but I don't understand them.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me with trial data in SQLite:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET randomStates = (SELECT colStates FROM
                        (SELECT * FROM first_table ORDER BY RANDOM())
                    WHERE randomStates IS NULL)
```

without the first SELECT portion, you end up with the same random value inserted into all the NULL randomStates field. (i.e. if you just do SELECT StateValue FROM counts ORDER BY RANDOM() you don't get what you want).

Comment: that actually didn't change anything... it still has the same value added to the randomStates.

Comment: The deleted answer from @Gordon Linoff is the correct one. This answer did not work for me.